# Count the vowels in a string including Y if its followed by a consonant

Tags: java

I have a program I'm working on that counts the number of vowels in a string. I have it working but I can't get it to count Y if Y is followed by a consonant. My VOWEL_GROUP is "AEIOUaeiou" it returns the number of regular common vowels but not 'y'. I have it look at the charAt(i) and see if it is pre-ceeded by something other than a character in the vowel group.
Thanks for any help. 
Here is the input and output to show the errors

```
 OUTPUT to console

 Input
 play. Why! Who!

 There are 3 words in the file.
 There are 2 vowels in the file.
 There are Y 19 vowels in the file.
 There are 3 sentences in the file.


 // START of countThe Y Vowels********************************************
    int  YvowelCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<myFile.length();i++){
         for(int j=0;j<VOWEL_GROUP.length();j++){
            if(myFile.charAt(i)=='y' && myFile.charAt(i-1)!= VOWEL_GROUP.charAt(j)){
                    YvowelCount++;
            }
       }   
}
// END of countThe Y Vowels**************************************************
```

Comment: Could you add some input output samples?

Comment: I don't understand the part `myFile.charAt(i)-1`, are you sure that's what you expect?

Comment: i don't understand too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to move the check for `y` out of your inner loop. In fact, you don't need the inner loop at all. Use `String#contains()` instead.

Next, since you need to check the character that comes after a `y` the `charAt()` index needs to be `i+1`. For the same reason, you don't need to check the last character of your file and hence the loop runs until less than `myFile.length() - 1`.

```
int  YvowelCount=0;
for (int i=0; i < myFile.length() - 1; i++) {
  if (myFile.charAt(i) == 'y') {
        if (!VOWEL_GROUP.contains(myFile.charAt(i+1) + "")) {
                YvowelCount++;
     }
  }
}
```

---

If you need to check the character that precedes `y` do it as: *(the loop would start from `i = 1` now)*

```
int  YvowelCount=0;
for (int i=1; i < myFile.length(); i++) {
  if (myFile.charAt(i) == 'y') {
        if (!VOWEL_GROUP.contains(myFile.charAt(i-1) + "") &&
                   Character.isLetter(myFile.charAt(i-1))) {
            YvowelCount++;
     }
  }
}
```

Notice, the call to `Character.isLetter()` to eliminate false counts like when a word starts with a `y`.

Comment: This returns all the 'y's In the string, "Play. Why. Who."  the only 'y' vowel there would be is in "Why" because it follows a consonant. That is where I'm stuck.. checking the character before the 'y' to see if it's a vowel. **I did get this to work by decrementing the my.File.charAt(i-1) so that is looks at the character before the 'y' and it indeed returns the correct number of 'y' vowels. Thanks**

Comment: Quoting your question: `count Y if Y is followed by a consonant.`

Comment: Also, do a `Character.isLetter()` check as shown in my update and start the loop from `1` now.

Answer (score 0):

The following is wrong, you surely meant i-1 to indicate another index. What you are doing is getting character at index i and substrating 1 to get another character.

```
myFile.charAt(i)-1
```

Besides that, make sure that i-1 is only used if i is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int  YvowelCount=0;
for (int i=0; i < myFile.length()-1; i++) {
  if (myFile.charAt(i+1) == 'y') {
        if (!VOWEL_GROUP.contains(myFile.charAt(i) + "")) {
                YvowelCount++;
     }
  }
}
```

check this.